# A relation on cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

$R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on $A$. Define relation $T=\{(x,y,z,t)\in R\times S : xRt \Rightarrow ySz\}$ on $A^2$. Check $T$ is equivalence relation or not.

I am in it is not reflexive. For it can be reflexive I need to prove followings.

For any $(x,y)\in A^2$, $(x,y,x,y)\in T$ i.e. $xRy\Rightarrow ySx$

I cannot see how can I prove or disprove this. Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Well, it seems like you already solved it, concluding it's not reflexive. I mean, you didn't exactly give a counter-example, but it suffices to find equivalence relations $S$ and $R$ with $R\nsubseteq S$. If $|A|>1$ this is possible: take $R=A^2$ and $S=\{(a,a):a\in A\}$. Suppose $a,b\in A$ with $a\neq b$. Then $aRb$ but $(a,b)\notin S$, so $aRb$ but not $bSa$, whence $(a,b,a,b) \notin T$.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks a lot for this very beneficial comment. Also, I can show it is not symmetric by using this, can't I?